# How to debug LAN issue with only 1 machine

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, nas

I have a LAN at home which is the following set up

1. Router
2. NAS
3. Desktop PC (wired via Ethernet and powerline)
4. Laptop PC (wireless)

When I try to copy a bigger file from my desktop computer to the NAS, I often get an error message telling me that the destination is no longer available.

If I try to copy the same file from my laptop (wireless) then it succeeds.

Using my laptop, If I try to copy the same file from the Desktop to my laptop, it succeeds.

It appears that the bigger the file, the higher the chance this occurs. For example, if I were to copy a file which is a few MB or less in size then I don't believe I've ever seen this error message. However, if I've got a file which is a few hundred MB or even GBs then this message is shown about 90% of the time.

This now suggests there is a 'fault' between my Desktop PC and NAS but I'm not sure how I can diagnose this.

*Edit*

If I do a continuous ping to my router I don't see any packet loss. I know there is a delay on my PC - for example if I plug my laptop into the router and perform a speed test, I get around 40mbs. From my Desktop PC (which is wired via the powerline adapter), I get around 8 - 16mbs (I'm not sure why this fluctuates so much over different days).

If I stream a YouTube video or an audio file then I don't get any breaks/disruption.

I was able to copy a 8GB iso from my NAS to my desktop and a 300mb video from my NAS to my desktop without issue. 2 days ago, I was unable to copy the same 300mb video to my NAS from this desktop (but I could copy it fine to my laptop as per the description at the start of this post).

A continuous ping from my desktop to my router (`ping 192.168.1.254 -t -l 30000') shows 0 packet loss over 3 minutes although it was as slow as up to 150ms. There was also only 1`request timed out`

[image]

Pining my NAS shows similar results (although there was no time out over the 3 minutes)

Comment: Do you experience delays while accessing the NAS with the desktop? Do you have any other issues accessing network resources with the desktop?

Comment: I've made an update @Seth - I think I should probably try copying *from* my NAS to my desktop... I don't see how it will make a difference but I will give it a go!

Comment: Did you test this without the powerline adapter? Depending on the consumers that are using the circuit you might get more or less interference.

Comment: Did you get any results moving the file from your Nas to your PC yet? @MyDaftQuestions

Comment: Post updated with the detail

Answer (score 0):

Tshoot 101 :

- look if there is errors on interfaces
- ping source to destination.  and source to every equipment between **
- if ping is clean verify logs of source and destination for errors that might point to issue.
- if that is clean then you need to start sniffing traffic which is a bit more complicated and usually left to specialist/ senior network technicians.

Notes:

- transfer speed may be respective of equipments internal power/capacity to send receive. its not because a port is synced to 1000Mbps that it will reach that particular speed. Buffers may fill up and you might experience issues then and there.
- **in proper use of ping, number of packets their size and flags matter: 
  on an Ethernet connection you should get < 10ms (time not data size) with packets of 1500bytes 1000 times with 0% loss with "no-fragment" bit/flag set.

*edit*:

- youtube adjusts to your wan speed. and your trouble seems to be local so you would not see any issue with youtube normally. Me i would suspect the NAS is not capable of going at the speed your desktop is going thus bottlenking at the NAS. the laptop being on wifi goes much slower than the PC thus the NAS would have less issues.

*edit #2*:
"which is wired via the powerline adaptor" there is your answer/reason , like was said in the comments powerline adaptors ( networking via power outlet) is much slower than regular Ethernet because the quality of the cable is much much less and there is much more interferences.

Comment: What logs? What logs are created when you try to copy files from 2 locations?

Comment: When the files copy, I can see it can get up to 5 or 6mb/s which should be more than enough. Plus, as per my edit, this issue doesn't appear to exist when copying from the NAS to my desktop (which seems really weird)

Comment: depending on what you are using to copy the file over network you may or may not have logs then ( samba logs ,openssh logs in the server) 5/6 mbps is pretty low if you are transferring large amounts 5/6 GB  (size of a DVD for example) would take about 15 min minimum like i said your best bet is ping. with large packets 1500bytes for about 1k or 10k counts if this does not reveal anything you might have other issues than the network itself. if you only get this going to the nas from the desktop this would point to the nas not being able to take the load but then again it depends on the nas.

Comment: also note that the connection might be half duplex on powerlines ( i have no idea but it would seem logical)  this would create lots of collisions. if you have a router inbetween the 2 device i would also look at that guy too.

Comment: hmmmmm... The router is naff :s

Comment: I've done a continuous ping to my router for 10 minutes with a size of 30000 bytes. There is no packet loss